Why does the 1st ionisation energy decrease from the 9th period to the 10th period
I’m currently looking at the ionisation energy chart within my chemistry textbook and while I know that there are not really meaningful periodic trends within transition metals, generally the ionisation energy increases going left to right. However, one notable exception to that rule is that the ionisation energy actually decreases going from group 9 to group 10. For example…

Cobalt (group 9) has an ionisation energy of 760 kJ/mol but Nickel (group 10) has an ionisation energy of 737 kJ/mol.
Iridium (group 9) has an ionisation energy of 880 kJ/mol while Platinum (group 10) has an ionisation energy of 770 kJ/mol.

What’s even more interesting is that the ionisation energy increases (as expected) from group 9 to group 10 in the 5th period with Rhenium having one of 720 kJ/mol while Palladium (group 10) has one of 805 kJ/mol. However, Silver (group 11) has an ionisation energy of 731 kJ/mol (showing the decrease in ionisation energy from group 10 to 11 rather than from group 9 to 10).
However, for the 4th and 6th periods, the ionisation energy increases from groups 10 to 11 as expected, with an ionisation energy of 737 kJ/mol for Nickel and an ionisation energy of 756 kJ/mol for Cu within the 4th period. Within the 6th period Gold has an ionisation energy of 890 kJ/mol.
Could someone please explain why this phenomena happens within the transition metals?

While I haven't personally checked your specific examples, usually, it's almost certainly the case that these elements that have lower ionization energies than the ones preceding them, do so because of orbital symmetry.
I encourage you to write down their electron configuration, and see for yourself if the elements that "break the rule" have an asymmetrical subshell, and would achieve a symmetrical subshell if they lost an electron.
A symmetrical subshell has its spins either full or half full. This gives it stability similar to that of a full shell.
Which is why that unstable electron doesn't require as much energy to extract out of the atom.
This isn't unique to transition metals, for example, oxygen exhibits a lower ionization eneegy than nitrogen which precedes it, and it's precisely due to the reason previously stated.
Lastly, I don't think it's useful to look at this phenomenon through the scope of 'groups', as you've noted yourself, this doesn't repeat across a particular pair of groups, rather its due to the unique electron configuration of each element.
